# wait for fs to finish reading files in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the following scenario:

I'm trying to have a user input a file in my language that I parse, and in that file he can include references to a file with methods in it, for now let's say it will be a .json file. So I have `fs.readfile` and in the callback I do `JSON.parse`. But the file the user uploaded uses those functions and before I run it I need the .json to be finished parsing and the functions added to my framework.

What's an elegant way to do this in node.js? I thought of using `readfilesync` or some kind of busy wait but there has to be a better way. I also thought about putting the call to the rest of the parsing process in the callback but there doesn't have to be a reference to a .json, it can use only the methods and what-not that I provide built into the language, and the reference can be anywhere in the file.

Comment: I use the async module to wait for each task. It has concepts like series, parallel or waterfall etc, depending on how you would like to complete them. https://github.com/caolan/async.

Comment: That's perfect! I need to up my googling-game.